# Obtener valor de div con JQuery en funcion

Tags: javascript, jquery

necesito realizar una función en javascript que me sume el valor de un determinado div (quiero hacer una especie de contador)

Tengo un listado de productos y cada uno de ellos tiene un div que se llama productoX (donde x seria el numero de producto)

Al presionar un botón yo quiero que me diga el numero que esta en ese div.

Mi función seria así:

```
function sumarItem(PRODUCTO)
    {
        var actual = $(PRODUCTO).val();
        alert(actual);
    }
```

Mi div y la llamada a la función es así:

```
<span class="badge badge-success badge-pill" style="font-size: 14px;" id="producto1">2</span>
                        &nbsp;
                        <span class="badge badge-success badge-pill" style="font-size: 14px;" onClick="javascript:sumarItem('#producto1');">+</span>
```

Pero el alert no me devuelve nada.

Comment: ¿Y qué error da este código?

Comment: Ese botón que mencionas es único o esta por cada producto ?

Answer (score 0):

`$(...).val()` es para `<input>` tenes que usar `$(...).html()` o `$(...).text()`

Answer (score 0):

La función `.val()` sólo funciona para elementos `input`, si quieres acceder al contenido de `#producto1` tienes que utilizar `.html()` o `.text()`.